# Calling a function and receiving: "Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1."

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

In a small project, I made a function to call another function under a condition.

```
import flash.events.Event;

var yspeed:Number=0;
var maxspeed:Number=5;
var accel:Number=.1;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, code);
function code(codeevent:Event){
    if(sprite1.y>449){
        code2();
    }
}


function code2(code2event:Event):void{
    if(yspeed<5){
        yspeed+=.5
        yspeed-=accel
        }
    if(yspeed>5){
        yspeed=5
    }
    sprite1.y-=yspeed;
    trace(yspeed)
}
```

I get the error:`Line 9 1136: Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 1.`
On line nine, which just has `code2();`

Note, I have tried doing

```
code2(Event);

code2(code2event:Event); 

code2(code2event);
```

and all of them come up with different errors.
I also tried changing names of the function, and adding `:void` after calling it.

Currently, sprite1's position is x=182 and y=482 on a stage that is 320x480

I do not have any clue on why this is happening.

Answer (score 3):

When you define a function with parameters which do not define default values, they are required (you *must* provide values for those parameters when calling the function). You can solve your problem by defining a default value of `null` like this:

```
function code2(code2event:Event = null) {
    // ...
}
```

Or by providing `null` explicitly when calling the function like so:

```
code2(null);
```

As for your attempts:

1. `code2(Event)` - Here you're passing a reference to the class `Event` rather than an instance of the Event class.
2. `code2(code2event:Event)` - This syntax is plain wrong, you only annotate (add the `:Type`) when declaring variables, parameters etc, not when providing values.
3. `code2(code2event)` - This would have been valid if there was an `Event` instance in your code allocated to a variable named `code2event`.

All that said, it doesn't look like your `code2()` function actually needs an event provided to it, I assume you just mimicked that portion from your above function `code()`. You can completely omit it and simply have:

```
function code2():void {
    // ...
}
```